# how can i block a particular url from a string array

Tags: java, swing

i have four url of different extension, i just want block a particular urls depending upon .extension.
how could i do that?
 i have use  if condition, but if does not give me my desire out put
i have done this code

```
String line[]={"https://google.com","https://www.facebook.swf","http://www.hotstar.com","http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login.js"};

for( int i=0;i<=line.length;i++){ 
    String ln=line[i];

    if(ln.endsWith(".css")){
        break;
    }
    if(ln.endsWith(".js")){

    } 
    if(ln.endsWith(".jpg")){
        break;
    }

    if(ln.endsWith(".fla")){
        break;
    }
    if(ln.endsWith(".swf")){
        break 
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("urls :"+ln);
    } 
}
```

how could i do this
if it will be in switch case or other  then please  help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: change the second and subsequent `if` to `else if`

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: If you only do a break, regroup the conditions into one with `||`. And you probably want to `continue` instead of `break` to check the rest of the array

Comment: What do you mean by "block"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `break` that stop the loop, if you want to check the full loop but skip a specific one with this logic, you need to use `continue`.

**Break** will stop the loop where it was, without any check.

**Continue** will stop the statement block of the loop and will check the condition of the loop again, this will not exit the loop.

I took the liberty to regroup the tests into one if-clause.

```
for( int i=0;i<=line.length;i++)
{ 
    String ln=line[i];
    if(ln.endsWith(".css")
              || ln.endsWith(".fla") 
              || ln.endsWith(".swf") 
              || ln.endsWith(".jpg"))){
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println("urls :"+ln);
    } 
}
```

But you could simply reverse the condition to print if this is not like `.css` or `fla` ... without an else clause

Comment: For the test, P1gu as a nice solution, I didn't took time to update this since he have done it

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to achieve this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String[] line = new String[] {
            "https://google.com",
            "https://www.facebook.swf",
            "http://www.hotstar.com",
            "http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login.js"
        };

        // End with .js or .swf
        String regex = "(?<=(\\.js)|(\\.swf))$"; // You can create a builder to build a dynamic regex

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String ln : line) {
            Matcher m = re.matcher(ln);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(ln);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

---

As @AxelH pointed out the case that we need to check if each string does not end with a specific extension. In that case, we just need to change the regex like this: `(?<!(\\.js)|(\\.swf))$`

I will also update the regex of original case for you to see the opposite: `(?<=(\\.js)|(\\.swf))$`

See more about positive and negative lookbehind here: [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: The problem is that this should be the opposite, he needs to check for those that doesn't have a specific extension. But this is nice.

Comment: @AxelH Thanks for the point. In that case, we just need to change the regex a little more complex like this: `(?<!(\\.js)|(\\.swf))$`. I think we still can build a regex builder in this case. I will update my answer.

Comment: I agree, this is just the regex to change (well the template of it). The solution is still good.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line[]={"https://google.com","https://www.facebook.txt"};
    String extensionToBlock[]={".com",".swf"};

    for (String url:line) {
        for (String ext:extensionToBlock) {
            if (url.endsWith(ext)){
                //url bloc
                System.out.println("not valid url :"+url);
                break;
            }else{
                //url ok
                System.out.println("valid url :"+url);
                //call a function with url ?;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution, but please don't post code only ... this is not helpful

Comment: It is best to include some explanation along with a code. Otherwise, you might risk people down-voting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String lines[] = { "https://google.com", "https://www.facebook.swf", "http://www.hotstar.com",
                "http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login.js" };

        for (String line : lines) {
            String extension = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("."));

            switch (extension) {
            case ".com":
                // bla bla bla
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                // its an image
                break;
            case ".css":
            case ".js":
                // CSS or Javascript
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Please note that switch over String is supported only in JRE versions > 6

Comment: When is Webserver will provide a download to a "file.tar.gz", he won't be able to filter those ;) Please, add some explanation to this code ... code only is not helpful

Comment: He would simply check over ".gz" unless he cares about "*.gz" and ".tar.gz"

Comment: Using tar and gzip is not the same file, and this is the first example that came to my mind, just saying this is not bullet proof ;)